# Jmeter-Master unexpectedly aborted with Shutdown hook

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to run load test, on CentOS 6.7, on distributed & non-GUI mode.

The test plan is supposed to run for 48 hours, but it is stopping at random intervals.

Both Java and Jmeter processes were not running. I could reproduce the issue on 2 different setup.

jmeter.log does not indicate any error except for the following lines:

INFO  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook started
INFO  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook ended

Comment: The lines you mention mean that JMeter was "asked" to gracefully shut down. Check the log prior to those lines. The simplest reason I would suspect is that test is starting to fail, and you have "Action to be taken after a sample error" set to one of the "Stop" options.

Comment: There is no error prior to shutdown hook messages. Actually i had configured the action to "continue" after a sample error. Same sampler works great from windows machine. I'm using the following command to run the script in background. nohup sh jmeter.sh -n -t xxxx.jmx -R <IP ADDR> -l /tmp/result-final.jtl &. Any help is highly appreciated, Thx.

Comment: How about the server side? Check `jmeter-server.log`. If you can't find it, check [this page](https://gist.github.com/kamermans/2830209) on how to enable it.

Comment: Jmeter-server.log is ruuning fine. Also Jmeter-server (slaves) are running from windows machine (master) using the same test plan without any issues, hence i'm not suspecting the slaves. i guess there must be a bug with centos 6.7 vs jmeter. is there any logs i can enable to debug this issue ?

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that JVM gets killed by linux kernel, due to memory overcommiting. Check if there's something like `allocation failed` or `killed process` in /var/log/messages, or any info on killing process in /var/log/kern.log or when running `dmesg`

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by recreating the containers with new set of Jmeter files.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing something similar and realised that when my terminal session closed/timed out, it was sending a terminate signal to all processes. To fix the issue, I just use nohup. So:
nohup jmeter -n -t .jmx -l .jtl -e -o  &